# Mask certain data based on user privilege

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need some inputs or guidance on the below scenario;

I have an existing aspx web application contains 10 different pages (search/list/details/reports etc..) using plain sql to fetch data back and forth. This application is to maintain student information. Would like to implement a new feature where certain teachers (access levels) should not be allowed to view student details (not to hide, masking a row in grid or table in all pages) based on some age (which can be configured in web config).

Would like to know the possible options to implement this feature in a best and efficient way in c# or sql server.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: This is question is extremely broad for SO. Since you are looking for SQL answer explaining structure of your tables may be needed to narrow down the question (I'm not a SQL expert, so I don't know what exactly would be needed)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not specifically looking for a SQL answer. Efficient way to implement either in c# or sql server.

Comment: It still likely depends on having some more specifics about the code and data

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't share code/data at the moment. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

If I was implementing a feature like this I would put a new property on the teacher to indicate the access level that they have.

Hopefully you can extract this logic into a shared location (and not on every page) but when you load your page you check if the logged in teacher has the necessary access level. If the user does not have the correct access level then you can either modify the query being sent to the database to exclude records that do not meet the age criteria, or you can filter what data gets sent back to the page to be displayed.

If you gave us some sample code or more details I could be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I can identify whether teacher has privilege or not. I did think of modifying query based on teacher privilege but I didn't want to exclude or filter the data. I want to return the data with identifier and those data should be masked in UI.

Comment: If that is the case, then you probably need to use javascript to do the masking of the data in your UI. I would recommend filtering the data before it goes back to the UI, depending on how you do it someone could inspect the page and still see all the information if it is returned to the page. If you never send it back to the page, they can't see it.